# How to use tf.gather with index vector that may contain out-of-range indices?

Tags: tensorflow, indexing

I have an index vector that may contain negative entries. How can I use this in `tf.gather`? My approach

```
params = tf.constant(range(5))
idx = tf.constant([-1, 1, 2])
tf.where(
    condition = idx >= 0,
    x = tf.gather(params, idx),
    y = -1
)
```

throws

> InvalidArgumentError: indices[0] = -1 is not in [0, 5) [Op:GatherV2]

because the `x` branch is evaluated for all elements. I do not want to remove the invalid indices because I need to retain the positional information, i.e. the desired output is `[-1, 1, 2]` (rather than `[1, 2]`, which I would get by discarding the invalid indices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows

```
tf.where(idx >= 0, tf.gather(params, tf.where(idx >= 0, idx, 0)), -1)
```

Output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([-1,  1,  2])>
```